# OOP in PHP, $this->

Tags: php, oop

Something is unclear in the code below for me as a newbie in PHP OO. For `$this->name`, where is `name` derive from? As for `$this->get_pinn_number`, why must I use `get_pinn_number` as declared like function/method name to get it work?

For extended class employee, why couldn't I use `$this->name = $employee_name` instead?

```
class person {  
    var $name;
    public $pinn_number;

    function __construct($persons_name) {
        $this->name = $persons_name;
    }

    function set_name($name="Jay") {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    function get_name() {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function get_pinn_number($pinn_number) {
        $this->get_pinn_number = $pinn_number;
        return;
    }
}


class employee extends person {

    function __construct($employee_name) {
         $this->set_name($employee_name);
    }

}
```

Thanks.

Comment: reading php oops manual wouldn't hurt.

Comment: `get_pinn_number` does not get anything. It is a setter and should be named `set_pinn_number`, also remove the empty return;

Comment: @conmen in your first part of the question are you asking why not use `$this->$pinn_number` instead of `$this->pinn_number`? Is that what you mean.?

Comment: You are writing in a bizarre mix of PHP4 and PHP5 OOP. `var` is no longer considered an acceptable way to declare variables, use `public`, `protected` or `private` instead to explicitly define visibility. Also, all methods should be declared with a visibility keyword. As it is, all your class members are (effectively) `public` - this is not necessarily a bad thing, but if that is what you want then explicitly declare them as such.

Answer (score 1):

The `$name` is from the parent class:

```
class person {  
    var $name;
/// ....
class employee extends person {
```

As `employee` extends `person` it gets all the properties as well.

Having said that, `var` is not the best way to declare properties. You would be better of using `public` or `private` for most.

Lastly, you *could* use `$this->name=$employee_name` in your code, but the idea of using the parent class function is to allow it to perform any tasks that it is supposed to do. Lets say that the function validates the data going into it because it needs to use it in another function of the parent class. If you just set it, it might well break another function you call later.

Answer (score 1):

You should change `var $name` to `protected $name` and then you can do it. Since the constructor in person is already setting the name you dont have to redeclare the constructor in employee to do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

`why I cannot use $this->name = $employee_name instead?`

You could, but it may be good practice to use the setter, as the main class developper may have added more code than `this->x=x`. Althought if that was the case it should have been set private to force you to use the setter.

Note :
Declaring class member variables is no longer needed. It will work in PHP5, but will raise an E_STRICT warning in PHP5 up to version 5.3, as of which it has been deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

For your second question You should use:

`protected` scope when you want to make your variable/function visible in all classes that extend current class.

`public` scope to make that variable/function available from anywhere, other classes and instances of the object.

`private` scope when you want your variable/function to be visible in its own class only.

Answer (score 0):

because in `employee` class `$this` denotes the employee class. `$name` is the variable of `person` class, so you can't call parent class's variable using `$this`. You can use `$this->set_name()` in `employee` class because it extends `person` class and is public method.